# Camera calibration patterns

Tags: camera-calibration

I would like to know if there is a process to generate camera calibration patterns.

We can use paint or any other graphic tool and set the precise measurements but then we need to hard-code the point positions or create a txt/xml file.

Is there a software that exports the data to a file that we can upload in our software.

What about 3D targets like boxes and/or cubes. Is there a method to generate the correct data points?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

For 2D targets such as checkerboards, I used to do it like user469049 describes. Which was quite time consuming. In the end I gave up and created a web tool that does all of the leg work:
https://calib.io/pages/camera-calibration-pattern-generator

Answer (score 0):

I'm using inkscape:
http://dominoc925.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/create-camera-calibration-chess-board.html

I usually create a pdf file used to print and save files as LaTeX with PSTricks extensions.

The tex file has paths, so for a square it has a \moveto command to set the starting point and it has \line to command to set the next points.

In the dominoc925 example they define black and white squares but I just define the black squares to avoid repeated points.

I have a simple file loader in my code to get the points, just search for the \moveto and  \line commands and workout the points from there.

For the 3D targets I treat each patter as one view because I don't have the tools to build a precise 3D target.

So instead of having different views of one patter like in the Matlab toolbox, I treat each detected pattern as a view.

In other words, if you have a 3D object then the target on each face is treated as a independent view.

There is probably a more professional way to do the job but this is my process :)

I hope this helps.